# Constraints not getting updated when changing bounds origin of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have an UIView A which contains another UIView B (subview of A). There is another UIView C (subview of the parent of UIView A) and it has constraints applied such that the top anchor of UIView C is aligned with the bottom anchor of UIView B and left anchor of UIView C is aligned with the left anchor of UIView B.

Now, when I try to change the bounds origin of UIView A, the placement of UIView B is updated but the location of UIView C is not changed, resulting in breaking the original constraints.

I tried doing setNeedsLayout and updateConstraints, but nothing is working.

When the UIView C is the child of UIView A, then it works fine.

How can maintain UIView C to be the sibling of UIView A, and maintain the constraints while changing the bounds origin of UIView A?

Comment: it's hard to say what is wrong without the code

Comment: I have shared the code here - https://ideone.com/WhF3Uf

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a minor bug

> left anchor of UIView C is aligned with the left anchor of UIView B.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *left = [myView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secondView.rightAnchor constant:0];
```

Try calling

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

after the bounds change

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried layoutIfNeeded/setNeedsLayout/updateConstraints but none seem to work.

Comment: Do you want UIView C to remain on the position when you change UIView A's bounds or you want it to move as well?

Comment: I want to move it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix-and-match explicit frame / bounds settings with auto-layout constraints. That, as you see, won't work.

When you run this line:

```
[[recognizer view] setBounds:CGRectMake(100, 100, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)];
```

You are changing the ***`bounds`*** of the view. That doesn't change any constraints. (Actually, setting the `bounds` doesn't even change the `frame`, but that's another issue.)

If you want to move a view, and maintain constraints between that view and other elements, you need to update the ***constraints*** on that view, not its bounds (or frame).

So you want to keep references to the constraints, or *find them when needed*, and update the `.constant` values as desired.

Here is an example of changing the center of your tapped view, by finding the CenterX and CenterY constraints (instead of saving references):

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

    // get the view that was tapped
    UIView *tappedView = [recognizer view];

    // get that view's constraints
    NSArray *constraints = [tappedView constraints];

    // we want to find the CenterX constraint
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstAttribute = %d", NSLayoutAttributeCenterX];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    // if it doesn't have a CenterX constraint, return
    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
        return;
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint *centerX =  [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];

    // we want to find the CenterY constraint
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstAttribute = %d", NSLayoutAttributeCenterY];
    filteredArray = [constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    // if it doesn't have a CenterY constraint, return
    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
        return;
    }
    NSLayoutConstraint *centerY =  [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];

    // we now have references to the CenterX and CenterY constraints of the tapped view,
    // so we can change the .constant values and the related constraints to the other view will be maintained

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                     animations:^
     {
         centerX.constant -= 100.0;
         centerY.constant -= 100.0;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

     }];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and great explanation. In my case, I want to change the view's bounds only. The reason being I want to show a subview that is currently clipped at the bottom. But, while I want to change the bounds, I also want to maintain the original constraints that were set on any other view with respect on any subview inside the view whose bounds I am changing.

Comment: You want to change the ***bounds*** or the ***frame***?

Comment: I want to change the bounds.

Comment: @Vishwas - You may need to re-think your approach, because auto-layout / constrains are not tied to **bounds**.